# UISegmentedControl tintColor

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm having problems getting UISegmentedControl to show the desired tint color.

```
// AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // need red tint color in other views of the app
    [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    return YES;
}

// ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *items = @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2"];
    UISegmentedControl *control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
    // would like to have this control to have a green tint color
    control.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:control];
}
```

How to make UISegmentedControl use the green tint color?

Comment: Have you tried this : `[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

Comment: Yes, sadly produces the same result.

Comment: Not very the best way to do it but might works. try to set the color for each subviews of the `UISegmentControl` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this ?

```
for (UIView *subView in mySegmentedControl.subviews)
{
   [subView setTintColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

But it actually appears that it is a known issue in iOS 7, I don't know if it has been fixed in iOS 8.

"You cannot customize the segmented control’s style on iOS 7. Segmented controls only have one style"

[UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)

Comment: The solution was to add the tint color to two levels of subviews (first is UISegment, then that has a label and an imageview). So thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Strange that the first appearance change works, but after that it's baked in. Oh well, will just create a category with the correct behaviour.

Comment: The category is a great idea, you should share it after, it might help people I guess.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up creating a category for the desired behaviour. Subview structure looks like this:

```
UISegment
   UISegmentLabel
   UIImageView
UISegment
   UISegmentLabel
   UIImageView
```

So two loops are required for the desired effect (otherwise some parts stay in old tint color).

UISegmentedControl+TintColor.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UISegmentedControl (TintColor)

@end
```

UISegmentedControl+TintColor.m

```
#import "UISegmentedControl+TintColor.h"

@implementation UISegmentedControl (TintColor)

- (void)setTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor {
    [super setTintColor:tintColor];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        subview.tintColor = tintColor;
        for (UIView *subsubview in subview.subviews) {
            subsubview.tintColor = tintColor;
        }
    }
}

@end
```